# Booting to initramfs very often

Tags: initramfs

My laptop boots to `initramfs` very often. When it does, I execute `fsck` as explained below, and always solve the problem momentarily :

```
(initramfs) exit

/dev/sda10: UNEXPECTED INCONSISTENCY; RUN fsck MANUALLY.
                     (i.e., without -a or -p options)

(initramfs) fsck /dev/sda10 -y
```

Then many problems are fixed, and I `reboot` and Ubuntu boots normally.

However I have to do it very often, more than tree times a week and I want to solve it definitively.

As suggested, SMART info are:

[image]

Comment: It indicates a problem with the storage device, HDD, SSD, etc. Use the Disks Utility to gather SMART info about the device.

Comment: I can't give you the link using my phone but search on 'enter y for fsck automatically"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As in this case the problem is always solved with `fsck`, it is possible to run `fsck` on every boot automatically.

`sudo nano /etc/default/rcS`

And do the change:

```
# automatically repair filesystems with inconsistencies during boot
FSCKFIX=yes
```

As it is a hard disk problem, think about backup important data. Now your disk is in **likely to fail soon**, If it changes to **imminent failure**, replace the HD.